# While upgrading wagtail-2 with Django-2 without effecting old migrations file. I am getting this 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_relation'

Tags: django, wagtail

I am trying to upgrade wagtail-1.9 to wagtail-2.0, and Django-1.10.6 to Django-2.0 but I am getting this error.

```
    delay = not old_field.is_relation
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_relation'
```

I don't want to delete or reset my old migrations file because if I delete the old migrations file or reset it I will be lost my data.

This is the full detail of error

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, core, faq, home, mailqueue, sessions, taggit, testimonial, wagtailadmin, wagtailcore, wagtaildocs, wagtailembeds, wagtailforms, wagtailimages, wagtailredirects, wagtailsearch, wagtailusers
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/home/razia/.virtualenvs/web-dj2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/home/razia/.virtualenvs/web-dj2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/home/razia/.virtualenvs/web-dj2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "/home/razia/.virtualenvs/web-dj2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "/home/razia/.virtualenvs/web-dj2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 159, in handle
        pre_migrate_state = executor._create_project_state(with_applied_migrations=True)
      File "/home/razia/.virtualenvs/web-dj2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 79, in _create_project_state
        migration.mutate_state(state, preserve=False)
      File "/home/razia/.virtualenvs/web-dj2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 85, in mutate_state
        operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, new_state)
      File "/home/razia/.virtualenvs/web-dj2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 144, in state_forwards
        delay = not old_field.is_relation
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_relation'
```

Comment: Please include the full stack trace of the error. Also, assuming the affected line of code is part of your own project (it doesn't look like code from Wagtail itself), please post a longer section of code so that we can see where `old_field` is being defined.

Comment: @gasman I added full details of the error.

Comment: @gasman `old_field` is defined in python site-packages. It's not in my project code, it's in packages.

Comment: It looks like your migrations have become inconsistent somehow - you have a migration removing a field which was never defined in the first place (according to the previous migrations). Unfortunately, without knowing the full project history it's hard to say how it went wrong or how to rectify it.

Comment: Install your previous Django and Wagtail and run makemigrations and migrate. Does the error still occur? Are any migrations created? Are any migrations executed? Only if you migration path is clean upgrade Django and Wagtail.

Comment: I'd also recommend upgrading one version at a time: first upgrade to Django 1.11, then Wagtail 2.0, then Django 2.0, then Wagtail 2.1, running `makemigrations` and `migrate` at each step to make sure they work.

Comment: @FlipperPA I am doing one by one version upgrade but still I got this error only. Any other ways to solve this error without drop database.

Comment: Are you a solo developer on this project, or are there others who rely on the migrations? If you are solo, you can declare "migration bankruptcy" and recreate your migrations from scratch without losing your data by running the newly created migrations with the `--fake-initial` option. This might be a way out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#initial-migrations Good luck!

Comment: @FlipperPA - Thanks, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrations sometimes need a little bit of manual intervention. If you are working on a project solo, you can declare "migration bankruptcy" and recreate your migrations from scratch without losing your data by running the newly created migrations with the --fake-initial option.

There are more details here, and I'd recommend reading up on it first:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#initial-migrations